# concatenate each Row with another row in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've a matrix 4X4 trying to concatenate rows like this :

```
1 with 2
1 with 3
1 with 4
2 with 3
2 with 4
3 with 4
```

at the end I have 6 even rows separately

Dear ((thefourtheye )) ,this Below is output of final code I will repeat one row if you can review

newline =

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
```

newline =

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
```

newline =

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6
```

newline =

```
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
```

newline =

```
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6
```

newline =

```
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
 5     5     5     5
 6     6     6     6
```

Comment: Before it was edited, you had an [r] tag on this post. Is R also an option? If so, you should make that more explicit and remove matlab from the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% Your original array is yourmat, it is square
newmat = [];
for n=1:length(yourmat)
for m=n+1:length(yourmat)
newline = yourmat(n, :) + yourmat(m, :); % Is this what you meant by concatenate?
newmat = [newmat; newline];
end
end
```

Comment: thanks soooooooooo much after editing your answer I get my answer

Comment: for n=1:size(yourmat),,,,,,
for m=n+1:size(yourmat),,,,,,
newline = [yourmat(n, :); yourmat(m, :)],,,,,,
end
end

Comment: but what about multi-row with multi-row I mean 3rows_with_3row

Comment: Haha, that was actually my original answer, but I quickly edited it because I thought you meant something else. Multiple rows is probably pretty easy: newline = [yourmat(n, :); yourmat(m, :)] still, but n and m are now ranges, i.e. newline = [yourmat(n:n+2, :); yourmat(m:m+2, :)]

Comment: but it'll give me error cause we don't have n+2 at the end for matrix

Comment: Then in "for m=n+1:length(yourmat)", change it to "for m=n+1:length(yourmat)-t", where t is newline = [yourmat(n:n+t, :); yourmat(m:m+t, :)]. You have to give a value for t.

Comment: every time I'll repeat one row I putted the output above

Comment: t=1 will give best result but this repeation is problem

Comment: Ok, can you post another question+example with exactly what you want and link it to here in a comment (so that I'm notified)? I think our problem is that I keep misunderstanding what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

more or less manually...

```
new = [old(1,:) old(2,:); old(1,:) old(3,:); old(1,:) old(4,:); old(2,:) old(3,:); old(2,:) old(4,:); old(3,:) old(4,:)]
```

but you should write a function if you need to repeat in other scenarios

Comment: by using for loop is better for concatenating

Comment: up to you, only you know what you're trying to do.  concatenating works either way.  but remember DRY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily do this with nested for loops and then store them however you want, but I chose to just store them into a cell array

```
someMatrix = rand(4)
storage = {}
iter = 1
newMatrix = zeros(2,length(someMatrix));
for ii = 1:length(someMatrix)
    for jj = i+1:length(someMatrix)
        newMatrix(1,:) = someMatrix(ii,:);
        newMatrix(2,:) = someMatrix(jj,:);
        storage{iter} = newMatrix
        iter = iter + 1;
    end
end
```